# How to replace a package that provides "php-http/async-client-implementation", if "remove" will complain about missing dependencies?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I want to remove the `php-http/guzzle6-adapter` from my composer.json and install the `php-http/guzzle7-adapter`

My composer.json:

```
...
"php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^2.0",
...
```

So for the first step to remove `php-http/guzzle6-adapter` i do this:

```
composer remove php-http/guzzle6-adapter
```

But I get a problem that I do not understand:

```
Problem 1
- sentry/sentry 2.5.2 requires php-http/async-client-implementation ^1.0 -> could not be found in any version, but the following packages provide it:
  - symfony/http-client Provides powerful methods to fetch HTTP resources synchronously or asynchronously
  - php-http/guzzle6-adapter Guzzle 6 HTTP Adapter
  - symfony/symfony The Symfony PHP framework
  - php-http/curl-client PSR-18 and HTTPlug Async client with cURL
  - php-http/guzzle7-adapter Guzzle 7 HTTP Adapter
  - php-http/mock-client Mock HTTP client
  - voku/httpful A Readable, Chainable, REST friendly, PHP HTTP Client
  - php-http/react-adapter React HTTP Adapter
  - swisnl/php-http-fixture-client Fixture client for PHP-HTTP
  - betalabs/guzzle6-adapter Guzzle 6 HTTP Adapter
  - neur0toxine/pock PSR-18 compatible HTTP mock library
  - john_zuk/php-nbp-api NBP (Narodowy Bank Polski) API client
  - phpgt/fetch Asynchronous HTTP client with promises for PHP 7 applications.
  - christophwurst/nextcloud-http-client HTTPlug and PSR7 adapter for Nextcloud
  - devster/http-client Symfony HttpClient component
  - gogoprint/guzzle6-adapter Guzzle 6 HTTP Adapter
  - nessworthy/amphp-http-httplug A small crappy adapter package to support php-http/async-client-implementation via. amphp/http-clien
  - pbxapi/php-http-fixture-client Fixture client for PHP-HTTP
  - phpgt/curl cURL object wrapper.
  - phpgt/curlinterface cURL object wrapper.
  ... and 2 more.
  Consider requiring one of these to satisfy the php-http/async-client-implementation requirement.
- sentry/sentry-symfony 3.5.3 requires sentry/sdk ^2.1 -> satisfiable by sentry/sdk[2.2.0].
- sentry/sdk 2.2.0 requires sentry/sentry ^2.5 -> satisfiable by sentry/sentry[2.5.2].
- sentry/sentry-symfony is locked to version 3.5.3 and an update of this package was not requested.
```

Can't I just "force" remove the package and install new one?

Comment: I'm confused, you want to remove `php-http/guzzle6-adapter` and also install `php-http/guzzle6-adapter`?

Comment: @ChrisHaas I'm sorry that was a typo I want to install the `php-http/guzzle7-adapter`

Comment: Have you tried **installing** the new package first, and removing the old one afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
composer remove php-http/guzzle6-adapter --no-update
```

and then

```
composer require php-http/guzzle7-adapter --with-dependencies
```

Comment: I get another problem on the `composer require ...` step:
`Problem 1
    - googleads/googleads-php-lib is locked to version 48.0.0 and an update of this package was not requested.`

Comment: Have you tried it with `--with-dependencies`?

Comment: You should be able to run a `composer depends googleads/googleads-php-lib` to see who actually requires it, too, and then check with that library to see if it really needs to be locked.

Comment: @ChrisHaas it says that my project requires it

Comment: Do as Chris suggested in the other comment. That's beyond the scope of this question. You have other things going on on your project that are hard to debug blindly. For a simple project that only depends on `sentry/sentry`, the above works perfectly fine.

Comment: @yivi but your answer does not remove the `php-http/guzzle6-adapter`from my lock file

Comment: In that case, I'd go through the [changelog](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and make sure there aren't any BC issues. If there aren't you can change the version from `48.0.0` to `^48`

Comment: You can't remove it without replacing it something else that satisfies `php-http/async-client-implementation`. That's the second part.

Comment: @ChrisHaas it is set as `^48` in my composer.json: `"googleads/googleads-php-lib": "^48.0",`

Comment: @yivi with `--update-with-all-dependencies` i get the same problem

Comment: that dependency is your root composer.json? Remove it, and install it again after getting around the guzzle issue.

Comment: @yivi I get a new problem once I try to reinstall the `googleads/googleads-php-lib` something with monolog/monolog that's not even my root composer

Comment: Ok, but you realize that way beyond this question, right?  If you have a complex project with many dependencies, you need to go one by one until you have in a proper state and you understand the project dependencies. We cannot possibly debug every possible `composer.json`. Even more so one we never saw.

Comment: @yivi yes I understand but the issue is I don't understand the error message:
`Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires googleads/googleads-php-lib ^53.0 -> satisfiable by googleads/googleads-php-lib[53.0.0].
    - googleads/googleads-php-lib 53.0.0 requires monolog/monolog ^2.2.0 -> found monolog/monolog[2.2.0] but the package is fixed to 1.26.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.`

This means I need to update monolog in a project that a require?

Comment: Again, try using `--update-with-all-dependencies` with your `require` command.

Comment: And also run `composer depends` on each dependency to see where it is defined, then go off to that library, check their changelog, and repeat.